# How can I update my Desire S from Android 2.3.3 to Android 2.3.4?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, htc-desire-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device)

How can I update my Desire S from Android 2.3.3 to Android 2.3.4?  Is it possible to update the OS for this model?

Comment: does not seem to be any update available at the moment from Settings > About phone (last option in the list) > Update (1st option)

Comment: Updates are usually mandated by your carrier. What carrier do you have?

Comment: My mobile carrier is Airtel in india. I dont think they will porvide the updates.

Answer (score 0):

madlymad's right, there is no official update.  [XDA has several 2.3.4 custom ROMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1146601), though.  Should you choose to go that route, read a few of the linked ROM threads and then follow the instructions for the one you want.